# How to change the url' name in URL.createObjectURL(file)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, bloburls, createobjecturl

I want to change the name that appears in the url when it is created, because it is not legible or identifying

```js
const file = new File([blob],"name.pdf", { type:"application/pdf" });
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(url, "_blank")
```

The url created is: `"blob:http://localhost:8081/c4ba621c-d314-42b4-9a8f-a4e87161f4d0"`, but I need it in this format: `"blob:http://localhost:8081/<"object's name">"`

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: Is there another option to create a url for an object?